# Converting React TypeScript to React js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to coding and I was wondering if someone can show me how to convert [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-ewnvx?file=/src/index.tsx) code that was shared on Sandbox from 'React TypeScript ' to 'React js'.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {TreeView, TreeItem, TreeItemProps, TreeViewProps} from "@material-ui/lab"
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";

function TreeItemX(props:TreeItemProps &{iconClickOnly:boolean}){
  // todo should call the original
  const handler:TreeItemProps['onLabelClick'] = evt => evt.preventDefault();
  const {iconClickOnly,...others} = props;
  const handledProps:TreeItemProps ={
    ...others,
    [props.iconClickOnly?'onLabelClick':'onIconClick']:handler
  }
  return <TreeItem {...handledProps} />
}
function TreeViewX(props:TreeViewProps&{defaultPreventedPrevents:boolean}){
  const {defaultPreventedPrevents,...others} = props;
  const originalOnNodeSelect = props.onNodeSelect;
  const preventingOnNodeSelect = (evt:React.ChangeEvent<{}>, nodeId:string&string[]) => {
    if(defaultPreventedPrevents){
      if(!evt.defaultPrevented){
        originalOnNodeSelect?.(evt,nodeId)
      }
    }else{
      if(evt.defaultPrevented){
        originalOnNodeSelect?.(evt,nodeId)
      }
    }

  }

  return <TreeView {...others} onNodeSelect={preventingOnNodeSelect}/> 

}

function App(){
  const [selected,setSelected] = React.useState<string>('')

  return (
    <TreeViewX 
      defaultPreventedPrevents={true}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />} 
      selected={selected} 
      onNodeSelect={(_,id)=>{
        setSelected(id);
      }}>
      <TreeItemX iconClickOnly nodeId='parent' label='Parent'>
        <TreeItemX iconClickOnly nodeId='child' label='Child'/>
      </TreeItemX>
    </TreeViewX>
  );

}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be to remove the types, for example:

```
function TreeItemX(props){
  const handler = evt => evt.preventDefault();
  const { iconClickOnly, ...others } = props;
  const handledProps ={
    ...others,
    [props.iconClickOnly ? 'onLabelClick' : 'onIconClick']
  }
  return <TreeItem {...handledProps} />
}
```

Just continue doing this, until you have your React code without the types in it.

Comment: Hello @jan-swart, I've been trying to debug the issue in the post below.  Might you have any guidance for me? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your assistance.  I get the following error when I attempt to compile:

> ./src/App.js   Line 17:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token
>
> 15 |     ...others,   16 |     [props.iconClickOnly ? 'onLabelClick'
>   : 'onIconClick']
>
> > 17 |   }
> >          |   ^   18 |   return    19 | }   20 |

Below is the code so far:

```
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import "./App.css";


function TreeItemX(props){
  const handler = evt => evt.preventDefault();
  const { iconClickOnly, ...others } = props;
  const handledProps ={
    ...others,
    [props.iconClickOnly ? 'onLabelClick' : 'onIconClick']
  }
  return <TreeItem {...handledProps} />
}

function TreeViewX(props){
  const {defaultPreventedPrevents,...others} = props;
  const originalOnNodeSelect = props.onNodeSelect;
  const preventingOnNodeSelect = (evt, nodeId) => {
    if(defaultPreventedPrevents){
      if(!evt.defaultPrevented){
        originalOnNodeSelect?.(evt,nodeId)
      }
    }else{
      if(evt.defaultPrevented){
        originalOnNodeSelect?.(evt,nodeId)
      }
    }  
  }

  return <TreeView {...others} onNodeSelect={preventingOnNodeSelect}/> 

}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <TreeViewX 
      defaultPreventedPrevents={true}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />} 
      selected={selected} 
      onNodeSelect={(_,id)=>{
        setSelected(id);
      }}>
      <TreeItemX iconClickOnly nodeId='parent' label='Parent'>
        <TreeItemX iconClickOnly nodeId='child' label='Child'/>
      </TreeItemX>
    </TreeViewX>
  );
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```